# Azure speech service- 'Hey' is getting recognized continuously during STT

Tags: c#, azure-speech

I am using Microsoft Speech Service for Speech-Text(STT) conversion that is Recognize speech from a microphone.I am able to convert the recognized voice from microphone to text. So, I am able to achieve the Speech to Text (STT) functionality with this. But, I am facing an issue as described below:-

Issue - During STT when there is silence that time the word 'Hey' is getting recognized continuously

I tried to do some R & D on this but I did not get much help. Attaching the screenshot for the same.

Is there any reason why the word 'Hey' getting recognized and how this can be eliminated?

If anyone has suggestions on how to proceed it would be much appreciated[image]

Comment: Hello @Divyashri Rao,
I spun up a simple continuous recognition speech mode console app to do a simple speech to text with dictation on.  I have uploaded the program.cs file here : https://github.com/Svijay-msft/Azure-Speech-Recognition/blob/master/Program.cs

Unfortunately, I was not able to experience the behavior you have mentioned. Can you please let me know if there is any additional configuration that you have at your end I m missing on my end? 
Also, sometimes I did observe, some background noise was generating some words.

Comment: Hi @sathya_vijayakumar-MSFT , Apologies for late response.I have added two more features to configuration as below: 
`config.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "en-IN";
config.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-IN-Heera-Apollo";`
Is this  anything related to 'Hey; getting recognized?

Comment: I was able to see the similar behavior at me end when I have en-in model. Looks like en-in model is extra sensitive minute disturbances when there is no utterance and it is being picked as 'Hey' by default. I don't see similar issues with en-us/en-gb/en-nz models.